# HTML5 - Empty space occurs when adding margin to div inside div

Tags: css, html

I have this piece of code:

```
  <body>
    <div class="page-top">
      *
    </div>
    <div class="page-bottom">
      <div class="contentbox">
        <h1>CONTENTBOX</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

And here is the stylesheet:

```
body {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

div.page-top {
  padding-bottom: 20%;
}

div.page-bottom {
  padding-bottom: 80%;

  background-image: url('http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/fog_at_the_pink_house-t2.jpg');
}

div.contentbox {
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 10%; <!PROBLEM>

}
```

The problem is: if I add to the `contentbox` a margin at the top (see code), instead of just go ten percent beneath the top line of the 'parent' div (`.page-bottom`), it just creates empty space above both div's.

Why does this occur? What I actually want is that the content div has just a margin of about 20% at all sides so it is a smaller div (`contentbox`) in a fullscreen div (`page-bottom`).

To clear things up:
[click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRCpa.png)

Thanks for your help, and if you need more information I will provide you with that!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should add `padding-top: 10%;` to `.page-bottom` to get more room between the `.contentbox` and the parent `div`. See the example below. Cleaned up some code as well.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page-top {
  background-color: blue;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
}

.page-bottom {
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 80%;
  background-image: url('http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/fog_at_the_pink_house-t2.jpg');
}

.contentbox {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
    <div class="page-top">
      *
    </div>
    <div class="page-bottom">
      <div class="contentbox">
        <h1>CONTENTBOX</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i like how this is exactly the same thing i said above, but yet somehow you give credits to this guy. Thanks @Roy to be so fair-play and thanks mpboom !

Comment: @JorelAmthor I guess the only reason is this guy posted working code. You must be complete with your solution as much as possible. Not only for the OP to mark it as answer but also future audience reference

Comment: @Reddy so sad people prefer to copy paste than to follow instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Because adding a margin will pushes material into the opposite direction, even if nested. You should add a padding-top to your .page-bottom instead.

Comment: Thanks, but what can i do if i want space between contentbox and page-bottom clear, like in the image. the background of page-bottom needs to be visible, but i need the contentbox to be just white.